# Raphael.js : How to drag one side of the path in my case?

Tags: raphael, javascript

I am using [Rahael.js](http://raphaeljs.com/) library.

If I have a path:

```
var mypath = paper.path("M10 10L90 90");
```

I would like to implement the feature that when mouse drag one side of
the path line, the other side of the path line keep in the original
position while the dragged side will move with mouse. That's like a
drag and pin feature. How to implement it?

I am not sure how to update
a path attribute by using raphael drag() function.

```
var start = function () {

},
move = function (dx, dy) {
    //How to update the attribute of one side of the path here
},
up = function () {

};
mypath.drag(move, start, up);
```

Answer (score 7):

You need a second element that acts like a "handle", make that element draggable and then update your line path:

```
var paper = Raphael('canvas', 300, 300);
var path = paper.path("M10 10L90 90");
var pathArray = path.attr("path");
handle = paper.circle(90,90,5).attr({
    fill: "black",
    cursor: "pointer",
    "stroke-width": 10,
    stroke: "transparent"
});

var start = function () {
  this.cx = this.attr("cx"),
  this.cy = this.attr("cy");
},
move = function (dx, dy) {
   var X = this.cx + dx,
       Y = this.cy + dy;
   this.attr({cx: X, cy: Y});
   pathArray[1][1] = X;
   pathArray[1][2] = Y;
   path.attr({path: pathArray});
},
up = function () {
   this.dx = this.dy = 0;
};

handle.drag(move, start, up);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TfE2X/

​

Comment: Yeah this is what i was talking about. @Duopixel has however used a circle instead of a rect element. +1 :)

Comment: i have a situation where i'm looping through json data and creating corresponding paths and circles for each element in the json data.  how can i access the path under the circle being dragged?  i have set a naming convention where the path under the circle is set to an id of "path" + "circleNameValue".  i've tried some DOM scripting tricks but doesn't seem to work well

Comment: link to the above example with 'code':   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625286/making-one-side-of-a-path-draggable-in-raphael-2-0

Answer (score 1):

Mask the end of the path with a transparent rect element and animate the coordinates from the current x,y to the translated x,y position of the rect element and keep updating the path simultaneously on mousemove.

Comment: your solutions looks incomplete Brut

Comment: Ah, it is but an idea. I can provide the necessary code if required, but the OP hasnt replied yet.